# Regression Testing on Cloud Servers

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloud, regression, rackspace-cloud

I have been asked by manager to do a research/study on using Cloud for regression testing. Currently we have a python script running on a central host that distributes test cases across different boxes, runs them, retrieves the results and compares them on the central host. We want to effectively replace these BOXES with cloud servers.

After doing my bit of research I have questions with regard to Cloud Servers:

1. How secure is the data in flight (while it will move between our central host and the cloud servers) Do any of the providers offer any encryption?
2. We require Red Hat Linux on all the cloud servers. If we need a Database on these servers, will we be charged even when no activity is going on the database? By activity I mean no Insertion/Updates etc.
3. Is there any charge for transferring data between the servers since we will sync a release across all servers before sending out test-cases to them?

Comment: I was the lead in a team who setup a unit, acceptance and unit testing in the cloud. Assuming your requirements aren't more complex than what you expressed above, pretty much any cloud provider will do. When we did it, we chose AWS due to Virtual Private Cloud support which we needed to hook to our VPN network since we had on-site resources and code repos we needed to get to from the servers in the cloud.
As for points 2 and 3, that's really up to you. If you want to use something like Dynamo, then it's on a per use pricing. If you are looking for a managed DB server those (continues ...)

Comment: ...those are priced hourly, not per transaction.
As rgbkrk answered below, the data transfer really depends whether you are planning to deploy a single-region or multi-region. However, bandwidth is sufficiently cheap to be considered a marginal cost, so I wouldn't lose my sleep based on ~10-12 cents/Gb transfer.

Comment: Is there a possibility of using our instances of DB on these servers? Does it get complicated (licensing fee etc ) with ORACLE? Considering all data in the tables gets truncated after runnning the testcases!

Comment: Oi! yes, licensing with Oracle is very, very tricky and pricey. You would be much better off by using an Oracle-preloaded instance and pay by the hour.

Comment: Also when we say "Shutting Down the servers when not needed" ? Do we get random servers ? I mean , will I be required to sync the release again ?

Comment: Yes, that I'm aware of if you shut down a CloudServer, you destroy it and you will need to reprovision it again. However, if you create a custom image of an existing server, reprovisioning it should be fairly straight forward.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### 1. Data in flight

As far as I know, you should think of the servers as any other server. If you do things in plain on the internet, they're still plain on the internet. **If you want it encrypted, use encryption**. Not everyone and everything needs encryption, as you have to strike a balance between performance, security, and utility. If you're transferring data via HTTPS, SSH/SCP, or SFTP you're probably fine.

Now, even if a provider says they encrypt your data for you, how much do you know about how they handle it? How do they handle keys? There are some [services that will manage this](http://www.rackspace.com/blog/keep-data-private-encrypt-at-rest-in-transit-and-in-use/) for you, but even that is up to your own trust. Better evaluate what they're doing and what access it gives them.

At least to Rackspace, [your data is your data](http://www.rackspace.com/blog/your-data-is-your-data-period/). Treat it as you want.

### 2a. RedHat

Both Amazon and Rackspace have Red Hat Linux servers.

### 2b. Server Usage

Cloud providers charge for when servers are running, not based on what you're doing/processing. You can always image the server and/or shut it down if you're trying to cut down on costs. Alternatively, you can also look at this as having the ability to create as many servers as you need.

### 3. Data transfer

If you're transferring data within the same datacenter, there is no charge. Just make sure you're using the internal IP addresses.

## Miscellany

If I have any suggestions for doing regression tests on any cloud provider, do use continuous integration (e.g. [Jenkins](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Meet+Jenkins), possibly your Python script) and configuration management ([Chef](http://www.opscode.com/chef/), [SaltStack](http://www.saltstack.com/), [Ansible](http://www.ansibleworks.com/), or [Puppet](http://puppetlabs.com/)). The more you automate the better off you'll be in the long run. All the ones I listed are open source projects that you can run yourself (or get managed support for).

Comment: Piggybacking on the encryption comment, if the data is being transmitted in a secure method you should be fine. Options include https for web services or using SSH (SFTP, SCP, etc) which are considered by most to be sufficiently secure.